# check frequency of keyword in df in a text

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a given text string:
text = """Alice has two apples and bananas. Apples are very healty."""

and a dataframe:

| word |
| --- |
| apples |
| bananas |
| company |

I would like to add a column "frequency" which will count occurrences of each word in column "word" in the text.

So the output should be as below:

| word | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| apples | 2 |
| bananas | 1 |
| company | 0 |

Comment: Could you share your code please, what did you try so far?

Comment: strill trying to figure it out. I think the logic should be like: if the word is in text: then name of row of column df["word"] exals count word in text - have a problem with writing the code tho

Comment: You should really try to write some code and ask for the specific problem. It is because you wont learn anything if you did not try at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['apples', 'bananas', 'company'], columns=['word'])
para = "Alice has two apples and bananas. Apples are very healty.".lower()
df['frequency'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x : para.count(x.lower()))

    word    frequency
0   apples  2
1   bananas 1
2   company 0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the text to lowercase and then use regex to convert it to a list of words. You might check out [this](https://regex101.com/) page for learning purposes.
2. Loop through each row in the dataset and use lambda function to count the specific value in the previously created list.

```
# Import and create the data
import pandas as pd
import re
text = """Alice has two apples and bananas. Apples are very healty."""
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'word':['apples','bananas','company']})

# Solution
words_list = re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
df['Frequency'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: words_list.count(x))
```